# CSS image background positioning

Tags: html, css

I want to stretch background by width, but its height size change depending on content. If the content is too small the background should be truncated. Otherwise, the backgroud should smoothly transit to black color in case if there are a lot of information. So I have:

```
body {
margin: 0; padding: 0;  
height:1000px;

background: url(images/background.jpg) no-repeat #000;

width: 100%;
background-position: left top; 
background-size: 100% 1000px;
}
```

But it has fixed size. I tried to change `height` to auto, but the background wasn't shown at all.
Is it possible to do this? 
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by background should be truncated?

Comment: The background's size is bigger than size of browser. So its height should be truncated by size of browser.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question but maybe this would help? http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 1):

```
html { 
  background: url(your_image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Should work easily enough in most browsers.

For IE:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='background_image.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='background_image.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

IE doesn't like web developers

Comment: The code snippet above is just stretch the background. It's not appropriate for me

Comment: I believe 'Cover' does crop quite nicely, the IE filters don't do such a nice job though

Comment: Yeap. I want to scroll the background

Comment: And if the backround ends, it should smoothly transit to black color

Comment: @RobWillis well, as I said, IE doesn't like us. It's almost impossible to make this work for IE.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work in <=IE8, however, there is an IE specific filter that does the job:

```
html {
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='your_image.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='your_image.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
    zoom:1;
}
```

Comment: so basically exactly my answer? just without the other browser coverage?

Comment: The IE bit was missing from your answer when I posted this (hence your edit!) And I pointed out that it was an additional fix for <= IE8 and not a complete answer as not trying to steal any credit

Comment: fair enough. Why not just comment on my answer though?

Comment: No code highlighting so not very readable with this much text